# How to implement a PHP function `die()` (or `exit()`) in Go?

Tags: go, exit, die

In PHP, `die()` is used to stop running the script for preventing the unexpected behaviour. In Go, what is the idiomatic way to die a handle function? `panic()` or `return`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `os.Exit`.

> Exit causes the current program to exit with the given status code.
>   Conventionally, code zero indicates success, non-zero an error. The
>   program terminates immediately; deferred functions are not run.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)


func main() {
    fmt.Println("Start")
    os.Exit(1)
    fmt.Println("End")
}
```

Even, you can use `panic`, it's also stop normal execution but throw Error when execution stop.

> The panic built-in function stops normal execution of the current
>   goroutine. When a function F calls panic, normal execution of F stops
>   immediately. Any functions whose execution was deferred by F are run
>   in the usual way, and then F returns to its caller. To the caller G,
>   the invocation of F then behaves like a call to panic, terminating G's
>   execution and running any deferred functions. This continues until all
>   functions in the executing goroutine have stopped, in reverse order.
>   At that point, the program is terminated and the error condition is
>   reported, including the value of the argument to panic. This
>   termination sequence is called panicking and can be controlled by the
>   built-in function recover.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Start")
    panic("exit")
    fmt.Println("End")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to print a stack trace after exiting the program, you can use [`os.Exit`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Exit). Also you are able to set a specific exit code with `os.Exit`.

**Example** (https://play.golang.org/p/XhDkKMhtpm):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func foo() {
    fmt.Println("bim")
    os.Exit(1)
    fmt.Println("baz")
}

func main() {
    foo()
    foo()
}
```

Also be aware, that `os.Exit` immediately stops the program and doesn't run any deferred functions, while `panic()` does. See https://play.golang.org/p/KjGFZzTrJ7 and https://play.golang.org/p/Q4iciT35kP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `panic` in HTTP handler. Server will handle it. See [Handler](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler).

> If ServeHTTP panics, the server (the caller of ServeHTTP) assumes that the effect of the panic was isolated to the active request. It recovers the panic, logs a stack trace to the server error log, and hangs up the connection.

Function `panic` is reserved for the situation when program just cannot continue. Inability to serve just one request is not the same as inability to continue to work, so I would log the error, set a correct HTTP status and use `return`. See [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#panic).

> The usual way to report an error to a caller is to return an error as an extra return value. The canonical Read method is a well-known instance; it returns a byte count and an error. But what if the error is unrecoverable? Sometimes the program simply cannot continue.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way to break a function in Go is to use `panic()`. This is the defacto way to stop the execution of an event on runtime. If you want to recover the panic you can use the built in `recover()` function.

**Panic** explanation:

> Panic is a built-in function that stops the ordinary flow of control
>   and begins panicking. When the function F calls panic, execution of F
>   stops, any deferred functions in F are executed normally, and then F
>   returns to its caller.

https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover

**Recover** explanation:

> Recover is a built-in function that regains control of a panicking
>   goroutine. Recover is only useful inside deferred functions. During
>   normal execution, a call to recover will return nil and have no other
>   effect. If the current goroutine is panicking, a call to recover will
>   capture the value given to panic and resume normal execution.

https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover

And here is a simple example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func badCall() {
    panic("Bad call happend!")
}

func test() {
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Panicking %s\n\r", err)
        }
    }()

    badCall()
    fmt.Println("This is never executed!!")
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Start testing")
    test()
    fmt.Println("End testing")
}
```